# SQLite less than operator problem

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite for a project and < symbol is not working in the query.

There is a table named Holidays which has a field of datatype datetime.

Suppose the table contains some dates of current year in the column HolidayDate.

```
SELECT HolidayDate
  FROM Holidays
 WHERE (HolidayDate >= '1/1/2011')
   AND (HolidayDate <= '1/1/2012')
```

The < symbol in the above query is not working. > symbol in the above query is working well.

Please help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not working". Do you get an error?

Comment: i am not getting any output even though there is rows which satisfies above condition. There is no error.

Comment: What is the definition of the Holidays?

Comment: The table Holidays contains only one column of datatype datetime.

Comment: There are no rows that satisfy above condition, because the only value that satisfy it are the ones in the form '1/1/2011something' and those do not look like valid dates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT HolidayDate
  FROM Holidays
 WHERE HolidayDate >= date('2011-01-01')
   AND HolidayDate <= date('2012-01-01')
```

(date format must be `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Answer (score 5):

There is no datetime datatype in sqlite.

Sqlite only has 4 types:

- integeral number
- floating-point number
- string (stored either as utf-8 or utf-16 and automatically converted)
- blob

Moreover, sqlite is manifest-typed, which means any column can hold value of any type. The declared type is used for two things only:

- inserted values are converted to the specified type *if* they seem to be convertible (and it does not seem to apply to values bound with `sqlite_bind_*` methods at all)
- it hints the indexer or optimizer somehow (I just know it has trouble using indices when the column is not typed)

Even worse, sqlite will silently accept *anything* as type. It will interpret it as integeral type if it starts with "int", as string if it contains "char" or "text", as floating-point number if it is "real", "double" or "number" and as blob if it's "blob". In other cases the column is simply untyped, which poses no problem to sqlite given how little the typing means.

That means '1/1/2011' is simply a string and neither dates in format 'mm/dd/yyyy' nor dates in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' sort by date when sorted asciibetically (unicodebetically really).

If you stored the dates in ISO format ('yyyy-mm-dd'), the asciibetical sort would be compatible with date sort and you would have no problem.

Comment: I am storing the date in ISO format. How can i get the output for the above said query. Can i use > and < for the dates

Comment: Yes, use `<` and `>`. Sqlite will compare them as strings, but in ISO format it coincides with comparing as dates. Just make sure you 0-fill the fields to fixed width, that is always use `01` and not just `1`.